# Showing that a point lies in the intersection of the closure of some subsets of $\mathbb R^d$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry

Let $I$ be an index set and $D_\iota\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ for $\iota\in I$ and $x\in\mathbb R^d.$ Assume that for every $\iota\in I$ there exists a sequence $(x^\iota_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq D_\iota$ such that $x^\iota_n\rightarrow x$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$. Does it follow that $x\in\bigcap_{\iota\in I}\overline{D_\iota}$?

Comment: Of course. If there is a sequence within $D_i$ converging to $x$, then $x\in\overline{D_i}$. Take a neighborhood of $x$, then there is an $x^i_n$ in this neighborhood, so it intersects $D_i$. This is true in every topological space. By the way, you should update the title of your question.

Comment: yes thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for each $i\in I$, there is a sequence in $D_i$ converging to $x$, this means $x\in\overline{D_i}$ for each $i$ (this follows easily since $\Bbb R^d$ is a metric space); in particular, $x\in\bigcap_{i\in I} \overline{D_i}$. Note we cannot say $x\in\overline{\bigcap_{i\in I}D_i}$ since we can take the rationals and irrationals in $\mathbb{R}$, which are both dense in $\Bbb R$ but have empty intersection.

Comment: thanks, I just realized while writing what actually the problem is...

Comment: What do you mean by "what actually the problem is..."? Is this not the question you meant to ask, either? Or were you referring to the question first posted?

Comment: Don't be mad. Andy is a good guy.

Comment: by the problem I mean that it makes a difference if you write $\overline{\bigcap_{\iota\in I} D_\iota}$ or $\bigcap_{\iota\in I} \overline{D_\iota}.$ My original problem is not exactly what I stated, it's a short version of it...

Comment: @hot_queen: My question wasn't meant to be condescending in any way; I just wanted to know if my answer still applied to his question, or if his question had changed.

Comment: @Clayton: your answer to the above question is perfectly fine...I just have to think about my original problem now

Comment: Your answer is perfect (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Because then $x \in \overline{D_i}$ for every $i \in I$.

Comment: OK. The answer has been changed too.

Comment: yes, I just realized that there are trivial counter examples for the question first posted...